# excel reference- VLOOKUP formula error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

VLOOKUP is great except every time i try to input the formula, i get an error message, "you may not use references to other worksheets or workbooks for calculated column criteria" anyone know how to get around this? thank you so much!

Comment: this is a follow up question to http://superuser.com/q/653356/259238

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel? Older versions do not support some links to external books or other sheets in some aspects like data validation or conditional formatting, but for a simple VLookup, a link to another sheet in the same workbook should work in any version.

Can you post your formula and describe the workbook in more detail?

The workaround technique for data validation and conditional formatting is to create a named range on the other sheet, then reference the range name in your formula.